# Add a new text element using jquery in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Hi i am designing a page in bootstrap,now i have to add a few new dynamic features using jquery.
I have to Add a new text field after the user clicks the Add option button(button id=btAdd).
The new field should come in the next row after that button.
here is the code.

```
<div class="col-md-12 well well-sm" role="main">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Please Enter The Filters Configuration Here</legend>
                <form>
 <div class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-7">
      <label for="Server URL">Server Url:</label>
      <input type="Server URL" class="form-control" id="Server URL" placeholder="Enter Server URL">
         </div>

    <div class="col-xs-7">
      <label for="pwd">Filter Name:</label>
      <input type="Filter Name" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter Filter Name">
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-7">
          <label for="sel1">Filter Type:</label>
             <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
                <option>Text</option>
                <option>List</option>  
             </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <label for="Filter Options">Filter Options:</label>

     <span class="inputWithButton">
     <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
      <button class="btn btn-info" id="btAdd">Add Options</button>
     </span> 
  </div>


    <div class="col-xs-7">
      <label for="Filter Label">Filter Label:</label>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Add Filter</button>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">        
      <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: This is relatively easy to do - have you tried anything at all yourself yet? If so please include it and we can help you.

Comment: and what did you do so far? when you click on the button, find the parent element, and you can use `after` or if you want to add more fields you can use `last` and `after`.

Comment: ya derek i have..i am just new to jquery so i am not able to figure it out.

Comment: do not use "bootstrap" as tag, use "twitter-bootstrap" instead, because it's another thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you need:

```
<button class="btn btn-info" id="btAdd" onclick="AddOption()">Add Options</button>
<div id="optionsContainer"></div>
<script>
    function AddOption() {
        var container = $('#optionsContainer');;
        container.append('<input class="form-control" id="addOptionInput" placeholder="Enter option">');
    }
</script>
```

OnClick calls a function which uses JQuery Append to add an Element.